# libopenssl building error | make error with Buildroot

Tags: gcc, embedded-linux, arm64, buildroot

I am facing an issue while using Bootlin Toolchain in Buildroot. I am using `aarch64 glibc stable 2020.08-1` I get below errors related to `libopenssl`:

```
 libopenssl 1.1.1m Building
PATH="/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin:/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/sbin:/root/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin" /usr/bin/make -j9 -C /root/raspcm4/sources/output/build/libopenssl-1.1.1m
/usr/bin/perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
    "-oMakefile" include/crypto/bn_conf.h.in > include/crypto/bn_conf.h
/usr/bin/perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
    "-oMakefile" include/crypto/dso_conf.h.in > include/crypto/dso_conf.h
/usr/bin/perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
    "-oMakefile" include/openssl/opensslconf.h.in > include/openssl/opensslconf.h
/usr/bin/make depend && /usr/bin/make _all
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF apps/app_rand.d.tmp -MT apps/app_rand.o -c -o apps/app_rand.o apps/app_rand.c
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF apps/apps.d.tmp -MT apps/apps.o -c -o apps/apps.o apps/apps.c
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF apps/bf_prefix.d.tmp -MT apps/bf_prefix.o -c -o apps/bf_prefix.o apps/bf_prefix.c
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF apps/opt.d.tmp -MT apps/opt.o -c -o apps/opt.o apps/opt.c
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF apps/s_cb.d.tmp -MT apps/s_cb.o -c -o apps/s_cb.o apps/s_cb.c
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF apps/s_socket.d.tmp -MT apps/s_socket.o -c -o apps/s_socket.o apps/s_socket.c
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF crypto/aes/aes_cbc.d.tmp -MT crypto/aes/aes_cbc.o -c -o crypto/aes/aes_cbc.o crypto/aes/aes_cbc.c
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF crypto/aes/aes_cfb.d.tmp -MT crypto/aes/aes_cfb.o -c -o crypto/aes/aes_cfb.o crypto/aes/aes_cfb.c
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF crypto/aes/aes_core.d.tmp -MT crypto/aes/aes_core.o -c -o crypto/aes/aes_core.o crypto/aes/aes_core.c
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF crypto/aes/aes_ecb.d.tmp -MT crypto/aes/aes_ecb.o -c -o crypto/aes/aes_ecb.o crypto/aes/aes_ecb.c
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF crypto/aes/aes_ige.d.tmp -MT crypto/aes/aes_ige.o -c -o crypto/aes/aes_ige.o crypto/aes/aes_ige.c
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF crypto/aes/aes_misc.d.tmp -MT crypto/aes/aes_misc.o -c -o crypto/aes/aes_misc.o crypto/aes/aes_misc.c
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF crypto/aes/aes_ofb.d.tmp -MT crypto/aes/aes_ofb.o -c -o crypto/aes/aes_ofb.o crypto/aes/aes_ofb.c
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF crypto/aes/aes_wrap.d.tmp -MT crypto/aes/aes_wrap.o -c -o crypto/aes/aes_wrap.o crypto/aes/aes_wrap.c
CC="/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc" /usr/bin/perl crypto/aes/asm/aesv8-armx.pl linux64 crypto/aes/aesv8-armx.S
CC="/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc" /usr/bin/perl crypto/aes/asm/vpaes-armv8.pl linux64 crypto/aes/vpaes-armv8.S
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF crypto/aria/aria.d.tmp -MT crypto/aria/aria.o -c -o crypto/aria/aria.o crypto/aria/aria.c
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/select.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:179,
                 from /root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:394,
                 from apps/s_socket.c:12:
apps/s_socket.c: In function 'do_server':
apps/s_socket.c:377:17: error: impossible constraint in 'asm'
  377 |                 FD_ZERO(&readfds);
      |                 ^~~~~~~
CC="/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc" /usr/bin/perl crypto/arm64cpuid.pl linux64 crypto/arm64cpuid.S
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF crypto/armcap.d.tmp -MT crypto/armcap.o -c -o crypto/armcap.o crypto/armcap.c
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF crypto/asn1/a_bitstr.d.tmp -MT crypto/asn1/a_bitstr.o -c -o crypto/asn1/a_bitstr.o crypto/asn1/a_bitstr.c
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF crypto/asn1/a_d2i_fp.d.tmp -MT crypto/asn1/a_d2i_fp.o -c -o crypto/asn1/a_d2i_fp.o crypto/asn1/a_d2i_fp.c
/root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/etc/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MMD -MF crypto/asn1/a_digest.d.tmp -MT crypto/asn1/a_digest.o -c -o crypto/asn1/a_digest.o crypto/asn1/a_digest.c
make[3]: *** [Makefile:737: apps/s_socket.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/select.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:179,
                 from /root/raspcm4/sources/output/host/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:394,
                 from apps/apps.c:19:
apps/apps.c: In function 'wait_for_async':
apps/apps.c:2707:5: error: impossible constraint in 'asm'
 2707 |     FD_ZERO(&asyncfds);
      |     ^~~~~~~
make[3]: *** [Makefile:705: apps/apps.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [Makefile:174: all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:295: /root/raspcm4/sources/output/build/libopenssl-1.1.1m/.stamp_built] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:23: _all] Error 2
```

This is the menuconfig:

[image: menuconfig]

Can anyone please let me know what this is about and how to resolve it?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: There's evidently some `x86_64` files in your include path...

Comment: Hello @Siguza, Do I need to set anything in `.bashrc` ? Like `CROSS_COMPILE` ?

Comment: Hello @Siguza, after setting proper PATH value, the issue got resolved. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the issue with properly setting the `PATH` variable. And also you can make the changes permanent by including them in `.bashrc` file which will be sourced on each login of the console. For example, in `.bashrc` include

```
export PATH="$PATH :path/to/bin"
```